# innerHtml='' out of memory and canvas always take memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

This is one test,I click the button named paint once,the memory grow more,faster and faster,how can I delete the canvas from memory,($('#div').empty() does not work)if it can not be resolved,I can display it,but every canvas will be biger and biger,because I paint always,can you help me?help!!!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="aa" style="position: relative;width: 500px;height: 500px;background-color: #048ca7;z-index: 0">

</div>

<script>
    var i=500;
    var uu=new Array();
    var ii=function(){
        var c=document.getElementById('aa');
        c.innerHTML='';
        var num1,num2;
        var canvas;
        var ctx;
        var str='';
        for(var j=0;j<=i;j++){
            num1=Math.random();
            num2=Math.random();
            str+=("<canvas id='"+j+"' width='100' height='100' style='margin-top:"+num1*400+"px;margin-left:"+num2*400+"px;position: absolute;z-index:1'></canvas>");
        }
        c.innerHTML=str;
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
            canvas=document.getElementById(j.toString());
            ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

            ctx.strokeStyle='black';
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(10,10);
            ctx.lineTo(80,80);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

</script>
<button style="width: 100px;height: 20px;margin-top: 20px" onclick="ii()">paint</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a reason for creating all this canvas elements? isn't one just enough? Also it should be `$('div').empty()` or `$('#aa').empty()`

Comment: yes,I need these all and I had tried this way like $('#aa').empty()

Comment: str+= is probably to large. Have you tried using document.createElement('canvas'); or at least generating the canvas elements 1 by 1?

Comment: yes,I have tried these all